# i want to send the data under the userid and also fetch the same data

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i am not able to send it under the current userid and also not able to fetch it for current userid.
basically i want to send the data under the userid and also fetch the same data.

1. So for that i want to change the current document name as the user id. but whenever i do that and i call _sendToServer() in an on pressed button it gives me error.

```
 _sendToServer() {
    if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
      _key.currentState.save();
      DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
      final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
      var data = {
        "name": name,
        "profession": profession,
        "message": message,
      };
      _db
          .collection('Profile')
          .document('KoMna0Hv7VXoeABwFTGH7LTo1No2')
          .setData(data)
          .then((v) {
        _key.currentState.reset();
      });
    }
  }
```

2. also while fetching data i am not able to do this. as i am getting error in the below code.

```
fetchUser() async{
    Future<List<Text>> getAllProfiles() async {
      List<Text> returnList = [];
      final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
      await _db.collection("profile").getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
        snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
          var keys = snapshot.value.keys;
          var data = snapshot.value;
          allData.clear();
          for (var key in keys) {
            myData d = new myData(
              data[key]['name'],
              data[key]['message'],
              data[key]['profession'],
            );
            allData.add(d);
          }
          setState(() {
            print('Length : ${allData.length}');
          });
        });
      });
      return returnList;
    }
  }
```

i must provide these key value pair for fetching the data but unfortunately i am not able to do so.

Comment: Could you please provide the error messages?

Comment: Thank you sir. the problem was solved!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I have added the orderByChild('id') and equalTo('${user.uid}') filed in the code with firebase user. and i also one more item to my list which is data[key]['id'], my current user id. this way everytime the user tries to fetch the data it will look into the list item for current userid and if it matches it will fetch that particular database only.

```
@override
  // ignore: must_call_super
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
      fetchUser(user);
    });
  }

  fetchUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    ref
        .child('node-name')
        .orderByChild('id')
        .equalTo('${user.uid}')
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      var keys = snap.value.keys;
      var data = snap.value;
      print(snap.value.toString());
      allData.clear();
      for (var key in keys) {
        myData d = new myData(
          data[key]['name'],
          data[key]['number'],
          data[key]['address'],
          data[key]['id'],
          data[key]['location'],
          data[key]['website'],
        );
        allData.add(d);
      }
      setState(() {
        print('Length : ${allData.length}');
      });
    });
  }
```

```
_sendToServer() async{
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
      _key.currentState.save();
      DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
      var data = {
        "id": user.uid,
        "name": name,
        "number": number,
        "address": address,
        "location":location,
        "website":website,
      };
      ref.child('node-name').child(user.uid).set(data).then((v) {
        _key.currentState.reset();
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _autovalidate = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please clearly indicate the changes that fixed the issue? An explanation would be appreciated. This way it will be easier to understand if somebody else has the same problem.